# Devise, ruby on Rails and asynchronous login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, asynchronous, devise

I am making a login system in Rails using devise, and I want the login to be asynchronous. I assume ajax is the only option?

If so, how is this done?

Comment: If you want anything to be asynchronous in the browser ajax is the only option...

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post to see if it's what you are looking for. https://hackhands.com/sign-users-ajax-using-devise-rails/

First you want to configure Devise to accept a JSON request, since that is what the AJAX will send. Go into `config/initializers/devise.rb` and change `config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr` to  `false`, then change `config.navigational_formats` to equal `["*/*", :html, :json]`.

Next you will have to overwrite the Devise Sessions controller to respond with JSON. Your sessions controller should look like so:

```
class SessionsController  resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    resource ||= resource_or_scope
    sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
    return render :json => {:success => true}
  end

  def failure
    return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
  end
end
```

After that you will need to map your user model to the Devise resource. You accomplish that by adding the following to your applications helper or the helper file for the controller where you would like to use the Devise AJAX functionality.

```
     module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

Then you will have to redirect Devise to use the controller you made instead of its own. Change your `routes.rb` file to look like:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {sessions: 'sessions}
```

Now you will want to change your sign in form. Generate the Devise views using `rails generate devise:views`. You should use the `form_for` helper and include the arguments

```
(resource, :as => resource_name, 
                 :url => session_path(resource_name) ,
                 :html => {:id => "sign_in_user"},
                 :format => :json,
                 :remote => true )
```

The rest of how the view looks is up to you.

Finally, you need to include Javascript to catch the AJAX response form your server. Here is an example in coffescript.

```
$("form#sign_in_user").bind "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    if data.success
      $('#sign_in').modal('hide')
      $('#sign_in_button').hide()
      $('#submit_comment').slideToggle(1000, "easeOutBack" )
    else
      alert('failure!')
```

Comment: Edited my answer.  Sorry for initial poor quality answer.